# Load image array into tableview image view via JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, nsjsonserialization

I was wondering if it is possible in general to load images via an **URL** which is parsed via **JSON** into an `UIImageView` in a `tableview`.

I tried this with no success in the UI and only two images in the log. I don't understand why he is showing me only 2 urls instead of 18.

```
   NSString *bildurl = [[arrayArtikelBild objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"bild"];
   NSLog(@"BildURL: %@", bildurl);
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:bildurl];
   cell.artikelImage.image = image;
```

I know that my parsing code work because I let it parse and display other things already (I use **NSJSONSerialization**).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could theoretically use:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bildurl]]];
```

but it's highly inadvisable since all the downloads will be done on the main thread + there's no caching. You need to load images asynchronous to achieve smooth scrolling. I'd recommend using https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage or AFNetworking's UIImageView extension (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: yeah I just had the same solution and the performance is crap....will check it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can  Using **GCD** (Grand Central Dispatch) for load image asynchronous

Using this will increase the performance of loading tableview definitely.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bildurl]]];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell.artikelImage setImage:image];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        });
    });
```

Comment: I would avoid using this exact solution because the URL will not be associated to indexPaths and therefore confuse time images on fast scrolling.